# Access keys and filter dict by value

Tags: dictionary, filter, jinja2, key-value

I'm pretty new to jinja2 and struggle on a simple problem:

I get an list of simple dicts to my template:

```
{"task1": true, "task2": false, ...}
```

I like to render a list of all task-keys, which have false-value.

I tried different tests and filters, but my problem seems to be, to access and check the value. So I returned to a boilerplate without checks:

```
{% for task in todo.tasks%}{{ task }},{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you're asking but if you want to iterate over a dictionary and print only the keys that have a value of `False` then do the following:

```
<ul>
{% for k, v in todo.items() %}
    {% if v == False %}
        <li>{{ k }}</li>
    {% endif %
{$ endfor %}
</ul>
```